# Standard for setting properties of existing object with PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a class in the model part that picks a data mapper, in my case I am concerned about an sql database and setting properties of an existing object.

So currently I am doing this to make my organization class

**Controller**

```
class controller
{
    public function invoke()
    {
    $organization = $this->model->organization($id);
    //pick view
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class model
{
public $database
//construct $database connection

public function organization($id)
{
    $organization = $this->database->get_by_id($id, 'organizations', 'organization');
    //$organization = new organization();
    $organization->stakeholder = $this->database->join_one('stakeholders', 'stakeholder_category', 'stakeholder_id', '1', 'entity_id', $id);
    $organization->document['document_affiliated_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('documents', 'authors', 'document_id', 1, 'author_id', $id);
    $organization->document['document_audience_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('documents', 'document_audience', 'document_id', 1, 'audience_id', $id);
    //people that are members of this organization
    $organization->membership['organization_membership_person'] = $this->database->join_one('people', 'membership', 'member_id', 0, 'organization', $id);
    //organizations that are members of this organization
    $organization->membership['organization_membership_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('organizations', 'membership', 'member_id', 1, 'organization', $id);
    //organizations that this organization is a member of
    $organization->membership['member_of'] = $this->database->join_one('organizations', 'membership', 'organization', 1, 'member_id', $id);
    $organization->event['event_affiliated_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('events', 'event_organizer', 'event', 1, 'organizer', $id);

    return $organization;
}
}

class organization//extends model if I were to add the funcion discussed below
{

//database table values
public $model_type = 'Organization';
public $id;//organization table
public $name;//organization table
public $stakeholder;//organization table join with stakeholder table (array)
public $membership;//organization table join with membership table fetchall (array)
public $document;//organization table join with document table fetchall (array)
public $event;//organization table join with event table fetchall (array)
```

What are your thoughts on a function in this organization class?

```
public function organization($id)
{
    $organization = $this->database->get_by_id($id, 'organizations', 'organization');
    //$organization = new organization();
    $organization->stakeholder = $this->database->join_one('stakeholders', 'stakeholder_category', 'stakeholder_id', '1', 'entity_id', $id);
    $organization->document['document_affiliated_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('documents', 'authors', 'document_id', 1, 'author_id', $id);
    $organization->document['document_audience_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('documents', 'document_audience', 'document_id', 1, 'audience_id', $id);
    //people that are members of this organization
    $organization->membership['organization_membership_person'] = $this->database->join_one('people', 'membership', 'member_id', 0, 'organization', $id);
    //organizations that are members of this organization
    $organization->membership['organization_membership_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('organizations', 'membership', 'member_id', 1, 'organization', $id);
    //organizations that this organization is a member of
    $organization->membership['member_of'] = $this->database->join_one('organizations', 'membership', 'organization', 1, 'member_id', $id);
    $organization->event['event_affiliated_organization'] = $this->database->join_one('events', 'event_organizer', 'event', 1, 'organizer', $id);

    return $organization;//End of proposed function which I am not currently using
}
```

This is my database class function called above

```
public static function get_by_id($id,$table,$class)
{
    try
    {
                    $core = self::getInstance();
        $core->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table where id = :id limit 1";
        $statement = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if (!isset($class))
        {
            $class = '__CLASS__';
        }
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->fetch();
```

Optionally I was thinking I might be better off doing a PDO::FETCH_INTO,$class

```
// Return results
        return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $exception)
    {
        die($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
public static function join_one($table1,$table2,$join_column_id,$person_or_organization,$where_column_id,$id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT $table1.name, $table1.id
    FROM $table1
    JOIN $table2 ON $table1.id=$table2.$join_column_id
    WHERE $table2.person_or_organization=$person_or_organization AND $table2.$where_column_id=$id";
    return self::get_by_sql($sql);
}
```

This works for me. Here are some of the things I am wondering what I should do.

My properties right now work like this Main object (organization) with properties set by the one fetch and then objects set into certain properties which are type (array) of the existing organization class. What are your thoughts on the typecasting (objects vs array in object)? Where should I be putting what logic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why no one else hasn't replied to you...I'm going to take a stab a it. Lets start with a little terminology, a class is a class, a function in a class is a method.

There are a lot of ways to implement an MVC system but I don't think your way is one of them.  You don't create a model class, you create a class called organization that is your model.  The general methods are

index/list
show/data
new/create
edit
update 
destroy

You controller handles the page logic, the goal is keep it at thin as possible. I'm not sure if you can have a controller be entirely a class...it maybe possible but I usually have mine as flat file. The view handles the output. You really should do more reading to MVC...there are tons of good writes up on it. You should also look into a PDO wrapper class. I can recommend http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/.  You should also read up on why singleton patterns are bad and how dependency injection is good.

So anyway....let me give you some quick code...its not going to be pretty or work but it should get the general idea across....looks like you want to display an org, in functional programmings you would probably code something like org.php?id=123....the better approach would be a REST setup /org/view/123...either way the codes the same but the way you call the code changes...

So the controller goes something like

```
$Org = new Org($dbClass);
if (isset($_REQUEST["id"]){
    $orgData = $Org->data($_REQUEST["id");
}
```

Now the model would be..

```
class Org
{
    public $dbClass; //stores db class

    public function __construct($dbClass){
         //its usually good form to type hint the db class interface
         $this->dbClass = $dbClass;
    }

    public function data($id){
        return $this->dbClass->run("SELECT * FROM org WHERE orgID = $id");
        // NOTE THIS IS VERY INSECURE 
    }
}
```

And finally your view

```
foreach ($orgData as $key=>$value){
echo $key." : ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I did create a model class, it's called model (my formatting above may be confusing). My model class has methods that call a data model class, in this case a database class (of which there are two for seperate mysql users insert vs update). I also use DOM and flatfile. In the database class I set the attribute (PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'organization') so now my organization class is made but not fully made. The model class method continues to fill my created organization with arrays associatied with that organization (person) but I could fill them with person objects instead?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm not clear what you are asking.  My response above is what I consider the best way to implement an MVC.  I don't really understand your approach but I don't think it will hold up once you start handling a large number of resources.